# Extractor de imagenes con python3

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un extractor de links, lo que hace este codigo es pedir un link, extraer el codigo del link y filtrar solo lo que esta dentro de la etiqueta src, en fin. ya lo he intentado en el modulo urllib3 no me funcionó, asi que trate de usar otro modulo similar el que estoy usando ahora se llama request

```
import requests,re
 
url = input()
 
r = requests.get(url)
s = 'img .*?src="(.*?)"'
b = re.findall(s,r)
```

el contenido de b deberia ser una lista de links encontrados por re.findall

Comment: y por qué dices que no funciona? Qué debería ser el contenido de `b` y qué estás encontrando? QUé problema hubo con urllib3?

Comment: el contenido de b deberia ser una lista de links por?

Comment: Porque no sabemos si ejecutaste el código (o el que usaba urllib3) y qué problema hubo. Para saber si estamos replicando el mismo problema

Comment: devolvio una lista vacia

Comment: Entonces no estamos viendo el mismo problema porque a mí me da un error con el findall y la forma en la que está recibiendo la expresión regular :/ Seguro es el mismo código?

Comment: si es el mismo codigo

Comment: es correcto yo creo que estoy teniendo problemas con el findall y el get

Answer (score 0):

Tu código deja de dar error si parseas correctamente la cadena con la url a procesar.

```py
import requests,re

url = input("La URL a revisar: ")
r = str(requests.get(url))
s = str('img .*?src="(.*?)"')
b = re.findall(s, r)

print( b )
```

Otra opción es usar beautifulSoup `python -m pip install bs4`) y probar algo así:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def pepito():
    url = input("La URL a revisar: ")
    dep = urlopen(str(url))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dep, 'html.parser')
    for element in soup.find_all('img'):
        if element.has_attr('src'):
            print (element['src'])

pepito()
```

La cosa es que... se necesita una página que no cargue todo usando estilos :)  Yo probé con `https://www.yahoo.com`